# how to keep number input as number data type

Tags: javascript, string, numbers

```
let a = prompt ("Input value of 'a'", );
let b = prompt ("Input value of 'b'", );

alert(a);
alert(b);
alert(a + b);

Number(a);
Number(b);

if ( a + b < 4){
    result = 'Below';
} else {
    result = 'Over';
}

alert (result);
```

So I was doing some kinda javascript practice and I encountered some issues with the above.

The output, take for e.g. a = 1, b = 2, instead of a + b = 3, the result is a + b = 12.

I thought that javascript auto recognise number as number data type, especially with the use of mathematics operators.

i tried:

```
let a = prompt ("Input value of 'a'", Number());
```

to specifically turn the input value into number data type but the problem still exist and it's puzzling me.

thank in advance for any helps given!!

Comment: `a = Number(a);` or `let a = Number(prompt ("Input value of 'a'" ));`

Comment: You'll have to convert your `Strings` into `Numbers`. To do that, you can either do `let a = parseInt(prompt("Input value of 'a'", ));` or `let a = +prompt("Input value of 'a'", );`

Comment: Apart from the `a = Number(a)` problem, it would be better to use `console.log()` instead of `alert()` to debug.

Comment: @Zenoo thank you! that's also a working solution, and in fact what I looking for as well to keep codes lean. Thanks for the input!

Comment: @chŝdk thanks for the tip! I tried actually but my webstorm console will display "ReferenceError: prompt is not defined" the moment i use "prompt". Same goes for "alert". But when I didnt use either of those, console.log(1+1), for example, works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting `a` and `b` as string so `a+b` is appending to string.

First you need to convert that to number and then perform `+` operation.

```
    let a = prompt ("Input value of 'a'", );
    let b = prompt ("Input value of 'b'", );

    a = Number(a);
    b = Number(b);

    alert(a);
    alert(b);
    alert(a + b);

    if ( a + b < 4){
        result = 'Below';
    } else {
        result = 'Over';
    }

   alert (result);
```

Working Demo is here:

```js
let a = "1" // value from prompt
let b = "2" // value from prompt

a = Number(a);
b = Number(b);

console.log(a);
console.log(b);
console.log(a + b);

if (a + b < 4) {
  result = 'Below';
} else {
  result = 'Over';
}

console.log(result);
```

It will work.

**Note:**

Instead of using multiple alerts its better to show/test values using `console.log()` which is a good practice.

Comment: Downvoter may I know the reason to downvote? It would be nice to mention the reason of downvoting. Thanks

Comment: oo ok thank you for the help! so by default, "prompt" will always capture the input as string datatype?

Comment: @Z.Jason yes you are right. It will capture as string then before performing any operation you need to convert it to `Number`

Comment: Apart from the `a = Number(a)` problem, it would be better to use `console.log()` instead of `alert()` to debug results.

Comment: @chŝdk thats correct but as beginners people are not much aware of console etc. They want to see some output on the screen.

Comment: @VicJordan Yes maybe but it's a bad practice to use three successive alerts in the page. That's why it's worth to mention that point.

Comment: @chŝdk alright! I will update my answer. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

The function `Number()` works right, but your problem is that you didn't reassign the value to the variable.

You need to assign it like this : `a = Number(a)`. This is how should be your code:

```js
let a = prompt ("Input value of 'a'");
let b = prompt ("Input value of 'b'");

console.log("Before Number");
console.log("a: "+a+"   b: "+b+ "    a + b: "+(a + b));

a = Number(a);
b = Number(b);

let result = '';

if ( a + b < 4){
    result = 'Below';
} else {
    result = 'Over';
}

console.log("After Number");
console.log("a: "+a+"   b: "+b+ "    a + b: "+(a + b));

console.log(result);
```